# CNSetSupportedSSIDs failed in iOS9.3.5

Tags: ios, ios9, ios9.3, captivenetwork

after iOS 9.0, it should use NEHotspotHelper to deal CaptiveNetwork. But I want get some Compatibility before iOS9. so I do the old way.

device: iphone6
iOS version:  9.3.9

my code is below:

```
+ (void)registerNetwork:(NSString *)ssid{
    NSString *values[] = {ssid};
    CFArrayRef arrayRef = CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,(void *)values,
                                    (CFIndex)1, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
    if( CNSetSupportedSSIDs(arrayRef)) {
        NSArray *ifs = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
        CNMarkPortalOnline((__bridge CFStringRef)(ifs[0]));
        NSLog(@"registerNetwork %@ success!", ifs);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"registerNetwork failed!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I slove this question. 
You can't do it success after 9.0
just act correct.